# Keep words in regex

Tags: java, regex

I just recently attempted to learn Regex for a project, and I have this:

```
patternstr = "<$Testing$>Go HERE <$Test2$>GO HERE 2 ";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<\\$\\w+\\$>\\w+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(patternstr);
```

Which returns

```
<$Testing$>Go
and
<$Test2$>GO
```

so how do I get the rest of the text while keeping the two  strings separate? Like that should return

```
<$Testing$>Go HERE
<$Test2$>GO HERE 2
```

and if I added more of the tags with text after it, it will return the third as well as the first 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add a (positive) lookahead, or a negative character class

Something like:

```
<\\$\\w+\\$>[^<]+
```

or (edited)

```
<\\$\\w+\\$>.+?(?=<)
```

Edited based on comments (should be positive, not negative lookahead).

I won't repeat Alan's comments about the end-of-line, they are right.

Comment: That second regex is wrong.  You want it to stop when it **does** see a `<`, meaning you need a *positive* lookahead, not negative.  You need to allow for a match at the end of the string, too: `<\$\w+\$>.+?(?=<|$)`.  The way you have it now, it will never consume more than one character after the `>`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you allow in the intermediate `String` this is fairly easy.

You just need to match `<$something$>something` repeatedly. If you do not have `<` in the intermediate string then all you need to do is

```
final String patternstr = "<$Testing$>Go HERE <$Test2$>GO HERE 2 ";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<\\$([^$]++)\\$>([^<]++)");
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(patternstr);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
}
```

Output:

```
Testing
Go HERE 
Test2
GO HERE 2
```

Explanation:

- `<\\$` matches the opening `<$`
- `([^$]++)` matches and grabs the content of the tag, i.e. everything until the next `$`
- `\\$>` matches the closing `$>`
- `([^<]++)` matches and grabs everything until the next `<`